# A model or framework to manage and audit a IFTTT like business logic

Tags: c#

I'm working on a car parking solution for an airport. There is a scenario where, when generating a new request for car parking card for internal staff, I have a plethora of if-else-then-else-if-repeat like logic. It is based on the parking service, staff type (immigration, customs, airport staff, police, etc), staff grade (where applies), gender, is manager,  etc.

I'm wondering if there is a better way instead of switch/if that'll generate a lot of code with minor condition changes and doesn't support readability at all. Coming from Windows Workflow background, I have an urge to do some kind of visual model but that may be an overkill as 1) these rules have not changed in 18 years 2) business users are not going to make changes if there are changes at all. So WF turns out to be too powerful.

Is there an alternative? I'm interested in having a verbose log/audit of the business logic to consult to to identify which strategy was resulted from given inputs.

Comment: Try source control.

Comment: Source control? As in TFS?

Comment: As in just use C# code and use something like TFS for auditing. Perhaps use some classes to incorporate some logic. Basically, bog standard programming.

Comment: I'm beyond bog standards here. The purpose of the question is to see if there is some solution between bog standard and Workflow foundation. This has nothing to do with Source control. If I say it parking service T1A-1Year and its for a staff of AirportStaff with grade 8, Male. My logic method would go through a series of switch and if-elses to return me Eligibility and Cost (can be free). There is more but its simple. All the code is there. Bog Standard. Manual log entries after each condition. Made as many child methods as I could. No readability.

Comment: I want to see if I can describe each case as a (named) scenario. And in log, I could just print Executed Airport1-Terminal4-Parking1A-1Year-AirportStaff-G8-Male-NonManager with parameters { bla bla bla }

Comment: Can do it but wanted to be sure if I'm not heading for re-inventing.

Comment: I have yet to see what problem you are trying to solve. Having lost more of my life to WF than I'd like, I know how bad it is. Also having worked on many frameworks in my life, I understand tooling is very important in the dev/debug process. Chances are any IFTTT would only make debugging harder, but improve writablity. Overall if IFTTTs worked well for complex systems, they would have replaced text based programming languages.

Comment: At the end of the day, you said that the business rules have been stable for 18 years, so I would use C#.

Comment: Similar feelings towards WF.